# GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found error when running project executables

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake

I am working on a project using boost 1.80 beta and C++-20. I'm compiling with gcc-11.3. I have some modules which have test suite that utilize boost unit test framework. Since updating boost from 1.58 to 1.80, I get the following error every time I try to run a test executable:

```
./Test_address
./Test_address: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./Test_address)
./Test_address: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by ./Test_address)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this, and what may be causing it?

Comment: This means you have compiled against a version of libstdc++ which is newer than what is installed on your machine by default. How did you install gcc-11.3? What are your compilation and link commands?

Comment: I installed gcc-11.3 by pulling the source and building it on my machine. I am using CMake to set up the build.

Comment: "installed gcc-11.3 by pulling the source and building it on my machine" ‎That's your problem right here. gcc comes with its own libstdc++.so and can build against it just fine, but executables will not find it by default at runtime. If you want to distribute your executable, try building with `-static-libstdc++`. If you just want to run on the machine you build, add `-Wl,-rpath=<path-where-libstdc++.so-in-gcc-11.3-lives>`.